# Missing comment

Tags: support, inbox, comments

Right now I have a comment in my "inbox":

**comment on Water Pressure in Free Fall
This doesn't get you differences in a single**

But in that thread I do not see any comment.

Georg

Comment: Well, everyone has an option to delete their comments, so that's probably all there is to it.

Comment: That was me. I deleted it almost immediately when I realized I had misread your answer. The StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ inbox doesn't notice deleted comments so you get the notification. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the timing of the comment deletion, it may or may not show up in your network inbox.